Router not seeing Pi Zero connected with ethernet cable
Let me start this off by saying that I had a working setup with PiHole running on the Pi Zero (v1) for a couple of years now. It's the non-WiFi version and I had it connected through an ethernet -> micro USB adapter. It's a headless setup, so no display on the device itself. I did everything through ssh.
After a power outage I had last night, I was no longer able to ssh into the Pi. I rebooted a few times with no luck. I reset the DNS configuration on the router to get internet back, but I've had no luck getting into the Pi since. I had a static IP set up on it which was no longer showing up in the router's connected devices list.
I have since re-flashed the OS on the SD card to the latest Raspberry Pi OS version using the Pi Imager tool. I configured ssh in the pre-flash configuration. I enabled DHCP on my router and connected everything back up, but it seems like the router still won't assign an IP to the Pi. Still not seeing it in the connected devices list, and running arp -a from my laptop does not list an IP corresponding to the Pi (I have checked all the addresses manually and none of them are the Pi). From my understanding, DHCP should be enabled by default on the Pi so the router should be assigning it an address. I'm trying to get ssh up and running so I can set up the static IP.
I've tried creating an ssh file on the boot partition with the SD card connected to my laptop. Booting the Pi after this and checking the SD boot partition again, the ssh file is gone. From what I'm reading this means that the ssh activation has worked. So this to me indicates that the system is booting up properly but it's still not discoverable on the network.
I am getting a solid green light on the Pi Zero and the LED on the ethernet port on the router is also lighting up when I connect and boot up the Pi.
I currently don't have a way to connect a display to the Pi and take a deeper look what's going on while the device is booted. I would appreciate any suggestions before I'm forced to start buying new cables in order to test things out further.
Edit: Well, turns out this was most likely a hardware issue with the Pi itself. I bought a mini HDMI -> HDMI adapter to connect a monitor and see what was going on. The Pi would start booting but rarely make it to the user login before a kernel panic happened. I can't remember the exact error now but searching around, people said these errors can happen due to inconsistent power supply. However, I had already tried several different power adapters and cables, all of which have worked with this Pi before. My theory is that the power spike after power returned after the outage might have fried a component like a VRM without really completely killing the Pi.
I have bought a new one and using the exact same adapter, cables and SD card, the Pi has now been running fine for several days with no issues.

have you considered the ethernet adapter is at fault? are you able to plug that in to some other computer? or perhaps using so-called "gadget mode" to access the pi


I would appreciate any suggestions

If the system booted to a normal state but networking failed, it would still be logging normally and that should have some indication of why networking failed.
The log is in binary format in /var/log/journal; there should be a subdirectory in there with a long arbitrary hexadecimal string name (eg. e2277f5a51b149c6bcd35fdc9120e830), and inside that a system.journal file.
Copy it out to another linux system into a new directory of it's own and use:
journalctl -D [directory path]

You can also use all the normal journalctl selectors such as -u and -S; probably -u NetworkManager should yield something.
If you have neither a display nor a system you can read the root fs on the SD card with there aren't many other options -- if you have a serial USB adapter you could try the serial console.
